# что происходит при выводе?

Tags: c++, массивы

```
int main()
{
 int arr[4] = {3,4,2,3};
 cout << arr[4];
 return 0;
}
```

вывод в консоль: -858993460

Comment: неопределенное поведение - чтение за пределами массива - происходит...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вспоминаем, что нумерация элементов массива начинается с 0.

```
int arr[4] = {3,4,2,3};
```

Итак,

```
arr[0] = 3
arr[1] = 4
arr[2] = 2
arr[3] = 3
```

А теперь скажите сами, что должно быть выведено тут:

```
cout << arr[4];
```